# Switch to first/last worksheet directly with keyboard

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to directly go to first/last worksheet in Microsoft Excel without cycling through all with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>?

Answer (score 7):

In Excel 2013, hold down ctrl when clicking the "next worksheet" arrow buttons on the screen to scroll to the first/last sheet. I'm not sure about previous versions of Excel.

Comment: Just to clarify, the answer below. Hold Ctrl and click the "next worksheet" arrow icon on the screen, or "previous worksheet" arrow icon. Not the arrow keys on the keyboard. So no short-cut key I can find unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

If you're up for inserting your own VBA, these two macros will do this.  Insert these into a standard code module. 
See [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/150988) for detailed guidance. 
The short version: type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor,
then select "Insert" → "Module".

```
Sub JumpFirst()
    Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub

Sub JumpLast()
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Activate
End Sub
```

Then close the editor.  Then, on the "Developer" tab, click "Macros" and click on one of these new macros, click on "Options..." and set the hotkey you want to use.  (It must be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + a letter.)  Repeat with the other macro.

Now you have to hotkeys to jump to first and last.

If the VBAProject you insert the module in the PERSONAL.XLS workbook, then these macros will be available at all times in all workbooks.

Answer (score 3):

As of Excel 2010 there is no direct shortcut for jumping to the first/last worksheet:

- [List of keyboard shortcuts in Excel 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-2010-HP010342494.aspx)

An alternative method would be to use the **Go To** dialog box. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> and enter:

```
SHEET_NAME!CELL_NO
```

Example:

```
Sheet2!A1
```

This will move your selection to cell *A1* in sheet named *Sheet2*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native keyboard shortcut to go to first/last worksheet in Excel.
Here is an **AutoHotkey** script that will let you do it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>

```sql
#IfWinActive ahk_class XLMAIN
^+PgUp::        ;-- Jump to the first visible sheet
    xlApp := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")      ; Creates a handle to your currently active Excel sheet
    try xlApp.Sheets(1).Activate                    ; Can use index or specific name
    SoundBeep 523, 150                              ; Let me know the ahk script is working.
    return
^+PgDn::        ;-- Jump to the last visible sheet
    xlApp := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")      ; Creates a handle to your currently active Excel sheet
    try xlApp.Sheets(xlApp.Sheets.count).Activate   ; Can use index or specific name
    SoundBeep 262, 150                              ; Let me know the ahk script is working.
    return
#IfWinActive
```

The `try` statement is there to ignore the error if the action fails, as in the case if you are editing a formula when you press the hotkey.

Comment: Thank you so much for showing how access the COM interface (or rather excel) through Autohotkey. I am glad to know that this is possible in AutoHotkey.